# Concat postgresql tsvectos without position offset

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

Based on https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/textsearch-features.html

```
tsvector || tsvector
The tsvector concatenation operator returns a vector which combines the lexemes and positional information of the two vectors given as arguments. Positions and weight labels are retained during the concatenation. Positions appearing in the right-hand vector are offset by the largest position mentioned in the left-hand vector, so that the result is nearly equivalent to the result of performing to_tsvector on the concatenation of the two original document strings. (The equivalence is not exact, because any stop-words removed from the end of the left-hand argument will not affect the result, whereas they would have affected the positions of the lexemes in the right-hand argument if textual concatenation were used.)

One advantage of using concatenation in the vector form, rather than concatenating text before applying to_tsvector, is that you can use different configurations to parse different sections of the document. Also, because the setweight function marks all lexemes of the given vector the same way, it is necessary to parse the text and do setweight before concatenating if you want to label different parts of the document with different weights.
```

Thus this query

```
select 'a:1 b:2'::tsvector || 'a:1 c:2 b:3'::tsvector;
```

will result in `'a':1,3 'b':2,5 'c':4`

Please advice is there a way to merge several tsvectors while preserving original positions (something similar to this):

```
select concat_with_preserving('a:1 b:2'::tsvector, 'a:1 c:2 b:3'::tsvector);
```

so it is equal to `'a':1 'b':2,3 'c':2`, eg same positions deduplicated and different positions are just merged (w/o offset).

Thanks!

Comment: That doesn't make much sense. Why would `c` from the second vector move to position 4, while the others retain their original position? Perhaps you can tell us what problem you are trying to solve with this "merge".

Comment: good catch, it is just a typo (with `c`).
the problem is that input can be free form i and I'd like to catch all of possibilities:
for instance postcode `1234AB` can be also written like `1234 AB`, and I want to handle postcode + house number, `1234AB 3` based on position.
but when tsvectors concatenated  - position gets off.

Answer (score 2):

Convert then to text, then concatenate them with spaces between, then convert them back.

```
(a::text || ' ' || b::text)::tsvector
```